# How do we use "Verschlimmbesserung"?

Tags: word-usage, style, colloquial

Sometimes we can hear or read of a "*Verschlimmbesserung"*:

> Schmidt bezeichnete Elena als Beispiel „für die schlimmste **Verschlimmbesserung** von Verfahren“. Was als Projekt zum Bürokratieabbau gedacht war, habe sich als völlig gegenteilig erwiesen.<sup>[Focus](http://www.focus.de/finanzen/recht/aus-fuer-datenbank-elena-steuerzahlerbund-beklagt-verschwendete-millionen_aid_647357.html)</sup>
>
> Der Jahrgangsclash ist nur der Auftakt an **Verschlimmbesserungen**, die das neue System mit sich bringt – und im Gegensatz zu den restlichen ist es eine einmalige.<sup>[taz](http://blogs.taz.de/neuewelt/2011/03/01/irgendwas_mit_guten_noten_das_g8nc-paradoxon/)</sup>
>
> Die Mehrheit hielt aber nichts davon. Es handle sich um eine **«Verschlimmbesserung»** gegenüber der Version des Ständerates mit dem Infrastrukturfonds, sagte Christian Wasserfallen (Bern, fdp.).<sup>[NZZ](http://www.nzz.ch/nachrichten/politik/schweiz/offroader_initiative_differenz_gegenvorschlag_1.9836166.html)</sup>

From my understanding the meaning of *"Verschlimmbesserung"* is the worsening of something  by trying to make it better. However the exact meaning and usage is somewhat unclear. Given that newspapers frequently use this term in quotes may indicate that it is a colloquial term rather than good style. But is that true?

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Verschlimmbesserung) gives us an uncomprehensible definition of both usage, and meaning by saying

> **Bedeutungen:**
>   1. das Verschlimmbessern; das Verschlimmbessertwerden
>   2. Ergebnis einer Verschlimmbesserung (1)

Other than my impression that these explanations are a *"Verschlimmbesserung"* by themselves I do not learn anything about usage or meaning (e.g. I have never heard of a *"das Verschlimmbessertwerden"*).

Is there anything known on who invented "*Verschlimmbesserung*", or what grammatical rules allowed us to build such a word? Is *"Verschlimmbesserung"* a mere colloquial term or may it be accepted when used in a written conversation or essay?

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verschlimmbessern

Comment: I strongly object to your first example! ;)

Comment: In general, Duden is not a good source for definitions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I love this word, but *Verschlimmbessertwerden* is a linguistical disaster.

You should never use it in an essay or any official documents. Instead rephrase your sentence, saying that the intention was to make it better, but the is result worse. I know there are many people who see the word *Verschlimmbesserung* as a *Verschlimmbesserung* ;p Or to say it in a different way: There are people who think this word is horrible.

Best synonym to take, just simple: *Verschlechterung*

Reserve *Verschlimmbesserung* for your colloquial use, especially in a humor sense. Also keep on the second meaning from Duden. It's the result of wanna-be enhancement. The act itself is rarely describe as *Verschlimmbesserung*.

Google Ngram Viewer does not find the word ;p

Not being asked, but interesting: 
There are discussions on [LEO](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=165031&idForum=1&lp=ende&lang=de) how to translate it. And [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=Verschlimmbesserung) also includes translations for *Verschlimmbesserung* in its database:

- *disimprovement*
- *improvement for the worse*
- *[schlimmbesserung](http://krautblog-ulrich.blogspot.com/2008/08/word-of-month-schlimmbesserung.html)* (**omfg!**).

English definition on thefreedictionary: [Reduction from a better to a worse state.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Disimprovement)

Comment: Verschlimmbesserung is a totally aceptable word in any context. The emphasis is on the not fullfilled promise to improve something and even worsening it. Verschlechterung is more neutral and may refer to exogenous factors leading to the degradation.

Comment: Verschlimmbesserung sounds like is was verschlimmbessert itself, intentionally. I suspect that because I think it is objectively disgusting, it's only that I can not tell whether it is more linguistically cruel, or aesthetically horrible.